# Problemas con jquery en entorno seguro https

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop

Estoy tratando de corregir un problema con una ventana de una pasarela de pagos para prestashop. Esta ventana es un pop up y es detectado como elemento no seguro en los navegadores y por lo tanto no se despliega. El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

class PaymentezDisplayPaymentReturnController
{
    public function __construct($module, $file, $path)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->module = $module;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $this->_path = $path;
    }



    public function run($params)
    {
        if ($params['objOrder']->payment != $this->module->displayName)
            return '';

        $reference = $params['objOrder']->id;
        if (isset($params['objOrder']->reference) && !empty($params['objOrder']->reference))
            $reference = $params['objOrder']->reference;
        //$total_to_pay = Tools::displayPrice($params['total_to_pay'], $params['currencyObj'], false);

         //variable timestamp
         $fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');
         $variableTimestamp=strtotime($fecha_actual);


        $cart = $this->context->cart;
        $idOrder = (int)(Tools::getValue('id_order'));
        $order = new Order($idOrder);
        $uid = $order->id_customer;
        $product = $order->getProducts();


        $total_to_pay = number_format(($order->getOrdersTotalPaid()),2,'.','');

        //$product_code = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product');

        foreach($product as $products) {
          $product_code = $products['id_product'] ;
        }

       //$cart = new Cart($idOrder);
       //$description="ProductOne";

        $ProductDetailObject = new OrderDetail;
        $product_detail = $ProductDetailObject->getList($idOrder); 
        //$description = $product_detail;

        //$this->context->cart = new Cart($idOrder);
        //$cart_products = $this->context->cart->getProducts();

       foreach ($product_detail as $k=>$v){
        $description .=$v['product_name']. ',';
       }

      // $summary = $this->context->cart->getSummaryDetails();
        //$vat = $summary['total_tax'];


        $cart_details = $cart->getSummaryDetails(null, true);
        $shipping = $cart_details['total_shipping_tax_exc'];
        $subtotal = $cart_details['total_price_without_tax'] - $cart_details['total_shipping_tax_exc'];


            //Modifique esta linea

        $sub = $total_to_pay / 1.12;
        $vatImp = $total_to_pay - $sub; 
        $vat = number_format($vatImp,2,'.','');
        //$vat = number_format($cart_details['total_tax'],2,'.','');

        $email = $this->context->customer->email;

        $appcode = Configuration::get('PAYMENTEZ_APPCODE');
        $appkey = Configuration::get('PAYMENTEZ_APPKEY');
        $tax_percentage = Configuration::get('PAYMENTEZ_IMPUESTO');
        $status = Configuration::get('PAYMENTEZ_STATUS');


        // Calcula la firma digital hash('sha256',
        $token = 'application_code='.$appcode.'&dev_reference='. $idOrder.'&product_amount='. $total_to_pay .'&product_code='. $product_code .'&product_description='. urlencode($description) .'&uid='. $uid .'&vat='. $vat .'&'. $variableTimestamp .'&'. $appkey;


        $signature = hash('sha256', $token);


        /************/

        // Url de Paymentez dependiendo del ambiente en el que nos encontremos
        $environment = ( $status == "habilitado" ) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
        $environment_url = ( "TRUE" == $environment )
                             ? 'stg'
                             : 'prod';

        //url
        $url_actual = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//"https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

        //directorio
       //$dir= plugins_url('/includes/confirmation.php', __FILE__);
       //$dir= dirname(__FILE__).'/confirmation.php';
       $var = Tools::getHttpHost(true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/paymentez/views/templates/front/confirmation.php';
       $fieldcredit = (int)(Tools::getValue('fieldcredit'));

       if ($fieldcredit == 1) {
            $fieldcredit = 0;
       }

        // Escribimos en el navegador nuestro iframe

     $url2 = $environment_url.'application_code='.$appcode.'&uid='.$uid.'&auth_timestamp='.$variableTimestamp.'&auth_token='. $signature .'&dev_reference='.$idOrder.'&product_description='.urlencode($description).'&product_code='.$product_code.'&product_amount='.$total_to_pay.'&success_url='.$var.'?status=1&failure_url='.$var.'?status=2&review_url='.$var.'&installments_type='.$fieldcredit.'&vat='.$vat.'&tax_percentage='.$tax_percentage;



        $rotativo = Configuration::get('PAYMENTEZ_ROTATIVO');
        $difcon = Configuration::get('PAYMENTEZ_DIFCON');
        $difsin = Configuration::get('PAYMENTEZ_DIFSIN');



        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(               

              'client_app_code'=>$appcode,
              'client_app_key'=>  $appkey,
              'email' => $email,
              'uid'=> $uid,
              'tax_percentage'=>$tax_percentage,
              'dev_reference' => $idOrder,
              'descripcion' => $description,
              'order_amount'=> $total_to_pay,
              //'telnumber' => Configuration::get('BLOCKCONTACT_TELNUMBER'),
              'telnumber' => "TelĂ©fono / Celular",
              'src' => $url2,
              'ambiente'=> $environment_url,
              'vat' => $vat,
              //'final' => $final,
              'rotativo'=>$rotativo,
              'difcon'=>$difcon,
              'difsin'=>$difsin,
              'taxable_amount'=>$sub,


        ));

        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/paymentez.css', 'all');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS('https://cdn.paymentez.com/checkout/1.0.1/paymentez-checkout.min.css', 'all');

        $this->context->controller->addJS('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
        $this->context->controller->addJS('https://cdn.paymentez.com/checkout/1.0.1/paymentez-checkout.min.js');

        //$this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/paymentez.js');




        return $this->module->display($this->file, 'displayPaymentReturn.tpl');
    }
}
```

Al parecer el problema está al final en la sentencia

```
$this->context->controller->addJS('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
```

Pero al cambiar http por https la página que contien el pop up deja de funcionar.

Talvez, alguna sugerencia para este problema?

Comment: Te sugiero que descargues el archivo de jQuery y lo uses localmente en tu proyecto así no te dará errores de protocolo de seguridad.

Comment: cambia el http a https, o descarga la libreria y usalas desde tu servidor

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el **path** de esta url de esta forma para que no te detecte la url como **insegura**:

```html
$this->context->controller->addJS('//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
```

Comment: Si lo he intentado, pero al hacer esto o cambiar de http a https deja funcionar la pagina donde se despliega el pop up